iPhone 11 Pro Max stuck in a boot loop with the Apple logo due to full storage, error 1110 when trying to restore with iTunes, 3uTools and 沙漏
I need to recover the data from my friend's iPhone 11 Pro Max 256GB. She used it until it was full, ignored all the friendly pop-up warnings to free up her storage, ignored the sudden shutdowns that happened a couple of times , and used it until it got stuck permanently in a boot loop at the white Apple logo.
She needs to recover her photos (she doesn't have a backup anywhere), but when trying to restore the device using iTunes, 3uTools, or 沙漏 (Shalou) in update mode (as recommended by Apple Support), it gives error 1110. It fails at the "Checking Filesystem" step (possibly because the storage is too full????), and throws error 1110. We've tried restoring both iOS 18 and 17.7, but the error persists. We've also used the specific restore mode in 沙漏 and 3uTools for fixing error 1110 while preserving user data, but still no luck.
Is there any way to extract the photos from the full, unbootable phone? If we can recover the photos, we are fine with performing a full DFU restore afterward to reset the device, but the priority is to recover the photos, as they are very important and weren't backed up beforehand.

What did Apple Support recommend as a next step after error 1110 was shown?

@nohillside Unfortunately, they only recommended looking through old iCloud or iTunes backups for the desired data and simply using Recovery Mode to wipe the phone. That won't work, since the phone is 256 GB, and her iCloud storage is only 5 GB, so I'm 100% sure the files she wants aren't backed up.
